# while loop , sum of list of numbers ,sum of each number

Tags: bash, unix

Using a "while" loop how i can display the sum of the following list of numbers   1 8 4 3 6 5 7 2. 
i  must create a sum variable to collect the sum of each value as the number is processed by the loop. bash  script

Comment: are the numbers in an array? are you reading them from a file? (where are the numbers coming from?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the numbers are stored in a file called `list_of_numbers` and that file in the current directory (your question does not state where the numbers are coming from), then you could calculate and output the sum like this:

```
sum=0
while read num
do     
    echo "$sum + $num = $((sum+num))";   
    ((sum += num))
done < ./list_of_numbers

echo $sum
```

Comment: is there is away to show the total for each time i add number like(1+8=9 then will echo the total then we will add the second number to the total which is 9+3=12 then will echo the total.....etc till we get to the final total 36